# Calling exe program with arguments from Prolog code in Windows

Tags: windows-7, prolog, swi-prolog

How can I run an exe program from my Prolog code and then use the output(which are Prolog predicates) produced by the program in my code?

Specifically, I have been trying to access the output of a program from my code in SWI Prolog in Windows 7 and then use this in my code for further processing.

Any guidelines are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run EXE you can use `shell/1` or `shell/2`, or `win_exec/2`, or `win_shell/2`. To read listing of prolog predicates stored in external text file you can use `consult/1`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried using `shell/1` or `shell/2` but it won't work. `win_exec/2` worked best for me. Also I have added a related question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144451/error-while-using-command-prompt-or-shell-using-process-create-3-in-swi-prolog)